# C# place X-Y dots on a coordinate system using charts?

Tags: c#, charts, coordinates, system

I want to place dots (or lines) on a 50x50mm coordinate system and I tried with charts but I realized that I need a fixed X 50mm and Y 50mm scale to place the dot on, not just place the values in the X and Y if you know what I mean.
Is it possible to use charts for this or where should I look?

Edit: I added two pictures to show how its shown in charts and how it should look in a CAD-program.

[image: Chart in VS]

[image: Chart as it should be]

Comment: _"if you know what I mean"_ - actually, no. Does this mean it has to be _actually_ 50mm on screen? Most charting components will have some means of specifying the x and y scales and transform to screencoords for you.

Comment: I added two pictures to show the difference in how it looks in charts and how it should look in a cad-program (or cnc program in this case) 
The curve is alway aproximately 50x50mm so that would be a good scale for this project, but it could also scale itself to the right size if that is possible.
Does that make it more clear?

Comment: The two pictures confuse me. I am supposed to look at the blue line and green dots and see that they differ by a matter of scaling? Because they don't. The green dots go up, remain flat, and go down. The blue line goes down and wraps around in a curve. Please [edit] your question and add specific details of what you have, how you get what you have and what is wrong with what you have. At a minimum show the code that defines the chart.

Comment: Since there has been no updates/edit to this question, I am voting to close it as lacking details.

Comment: I had too little time and saw that maybe system.drawing is a better way to go so I wanted to check that out before bothering you more.